# What is the law regarding crossing the street on a red light as a pedestrian?

Tags: united-states, new-york-city, traffic

What is the law regarding crossing the street on red (as a pedestrian)

If a car takes a red, that is a driving violation and they get a ticket...

---

I'm asking about pedestrians, specifically in NYC it is a *very* common thing, and just about everyone does it.

I've seen people do it in front of cops, and nothing happened - it's the norm in NYC

Is it legal? is it just not enforced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to New York state law [VAT § 1111](http://codes.findlaw.com/ny/vehicle-and-traffic-law/vat-sect-1111.html)(d)(4):

> Unless otherwise directed by a pedestrian-control signal as provided in section eleven hundred twelve, pedestrians facing any steady red signal shall not enter the roadway.

[VAT § 1112](http://codes.findlaw.com/ny/vehicle-and-traffic-law/vat-sect-1112.html) says they can't enter the intersection when a DON'T WALK (flashing or not) is showing, but can continue if they're already in the intersection.

And just to be clear about the illegality, [VAT § 1001](http://codes.findlaw.com/ny/vehicle-and-traffic-law/vat-sect-1101.html) says:

> It is unlawful and, unless otherwise declared in this title with respect to particular offenses, it is a traffic infraction for any person to do any act forbidden or fail to perform any act required in this title.

So the answer is, it's a traffic infraction, and illegal.

Answer (score -1):

It’s not legal.

As to why it’s not enforced:

- the legal answer is because police have discretion on which laws they choose to enforce
- the political answer you need to ask for on politics.se